# Case insensitive routing in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I would like to have a url that is domain.com/Test/index route to the same destination as domain.com/test/index. I have seen some examples on how to do this for a specific page but this does not work for me. I would like all urls in my site to be case insensitive. Is there a way to do this in a CakePHP site?

Comment: This particular example actually happens to work fine by default. Do you also want `domain.com/TeSt/InDeX` to work the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to implement a custom Routing class.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes