# Easy way to add case insensitive routing in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
Router::connect('/(?i:about)', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'about'));
```

[used to work in CakePHP 1.2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cake-php/E2Stqi9S708) but it seems to not be working in CakePHP 2.x

The only other solution that I see is to use the options to set a regular expression that will match against the a flag in the rout, but it seems rather convoluted for something so simple:

```
Router::connect('/:aboutFlag', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'about'),array("aboutFlag"=>"[aA]bout"));
```

Is there an easier solution more akin to how it was done in cake 1.2?

Comment: Related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105941/case-insensitive-routing-in-cakephp).

Comment: Thanks. I had already searched stack overflow too, and seen that response. Notice my question is if there is an easier way, creating a custom routing class is classified under *harder* :)

Comment: The answer I finally got to this question too is here, fyi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526099/cakephp-routing-in-php-too

Comment: Thanks, I've added a pull request in the Cake documentation describing the answer you received: https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/390/commits

Answer (score 0):

```
Router::connect('/:aboutFlag', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'about'),array("aboutFlag"=>"(?i:about)"));
```

This stems from the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526099/cakephp-routing-in-php-too)