# Cakephp routing (in PHP too)

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.1

I am using Cake, but how do I make the routing like:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index'));
```

case insensitve?

For instance:

```
Router::connect
(
    '/:user', 
    array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'contentProfile', 1),
    array('user' => 'hellouser')
);
```

MY_URL.com/hellouser works fine but not MY_URL.com/HelloUser does NOT route correctly.

And I have tried /heelouser/i and still nothing.

Comment: to be like twitter:  http://twitter.com/EV and http://twitter.com/ev and why does it matter what I need it for?

Comment: either you have to use .htaccess to rewrite your urls to upper to lower and vice versa or make your apache case insensitive

Comment: '/' is already case insensitive

Comment: no there is a cakephp why to do it with preg_match

Comment: Like AD7six said "/" is already case insensitive

Comment: Give a real example, and you then at least stand a chance of getting a real answer

Comment: would you mind clarifying the upper and lower case forms of '/' ?

Comment: @AD7six do you know anything about cake routing or cakephp?

Comment: no chris, @ADmad and I are complete noobs. https://github.com/cakephp?tab=members

Comment: btw "why does it matter.." isn't a very nice tone when asking for help on a public forum.

Comment: so why is my route not working, no one has an answer...

Comment: me too, just following what the cakebook says http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: in what way is it not working.. I don't have the patience to pull info out of you I'm afraid.

Comment: its in my edit, i use the above route, and type myurl.com/hellouser and it routes, but myurl.com/HelloUser does not and looks for HelloUser controller

Comment: "and looks for HelloUser controller" is not in your edit. "does NOT route correctly (no further clarification)" is in your edit - good luck.

Comment: can you not understand my edit, looks pretty clear to me what I'm asking?

Comment: Why do you want to match a specific user in the route? Just pass the name through to a controller where you do with it whatever you want. You're not going to make a new route per user anyway, right?

Comment: i am not going to make a new route, just for certain special users right now, so i just need this answer, should be simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements), you can use regular expressions to restrict matching route elements. The regex snippet you are looking for is:

```
'(?i:hellouser)'
```

### Route definition

Putting the docs and your specific regex together, here's a route that will match the url `/hellouser` in a case insensitive manner:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:user', 
    array('controller' => 'teachers', 'action' => 'contentProfile', 1),
    array('user' => '(?i:hellouser)')
);
```

The third argument is used to restrict the possible values of route elements - in this case to "hellouser" in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: it would have worked in cake 1.2 but in 2 they took it out

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690966/easy-way-to-add-case-insensitive-routing-in-cakephp-2

Comment: @chris you still don't seem to get that @ADmad is part of the core team (and me). That means you can be quite sure information provided is not fundamentally flawed. What that means here is you're reading it wrong - `array('user' => put regex here)` is what you should be doing. there are examples of this [in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements)

Comment: obviously I know you are part of the core team, but the answer above isn't working

Comment: i'm not the only one online with that problem, as you can see by the stack overflow link in my comments, but my answer works correctly

Comment: Yay +1 ADmad. You can tell his answer was going to be good because he doesn't have a set of numbers at the end of his nickname.

Comment: what's with the numbers at the end of the nickname comment mean?